# Is there a way to change TextField text input color from theme configuration in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I know there is a way to change text input color of TextField using the `style: TextStyle()` property, but I want to change the text color from the `ThemeData` widget, when first setting up the theme for the whole app `MaterialApp(theme: ThemeData...)`.
Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: which color you like to provide from `ThemeData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `TextStyle` for `TextField` is `subtitle1`. You can change it on theme level.

> If `style` is null, defaults to the `subtitle1` text style from the current [Theme].

```dart
 return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                subtitle1: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
              )),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
```

Comment: This is not what i meant, as I said I know how to change the color inside TextStyle...but I want to change the color inside ThemeData widget when first setting theme data for the global MaterialApp

Comment: I've updated the answer themelevel.

Answer (score 1):

Update 2022 - The more modern way is to use `TextTheme.titleMedium` from `Typography.material2021()`.

```
final x = MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      textTheme: Typography.material2021().white.copyWith(
          // This will be the style of entered TextField text
          titleMedium: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              fontFamily: FontFamily.poppins)),
    ));
```

Using `Typography.material2018()` (`textTheme.subtitle1`) will eventually be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
```

Replace `primaryColor` with one of many colors defined in `ThemeData`.

**UPDATED:**

You can define your own `Theme` as follows:

```
final myTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
  typography: Typography.material2018(),
  ...
  textTheme: myTextTheme,
  ...
);

final myTextTheme = TextTheme(
  headline1: TextStyle(...), // set your color in here
  ...
  subtitle1: TextStyle(...), // set your color in here
  ...
);
```

If you only want to change the text color of `subtitle1`, you can use this:

```
final myTextTheme = ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
  subtitle1: ThemeData.light().textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
    color: Colors.amber,
  ),
);
```

In your main app:

```
return MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: myTheme,
  ...
);
```

Comment: This is not what i meant, as I said I know how to change the color inside TextStyle...but I want to change the color inside ThemeData widget when first setting theme data for the global MaterialApp